# How to disable the fallback feature for Timber\Menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

In Timber, we can use `Timber\Menu` to make a standard WordPress menu available to the Twig template as an object. This replaces what the `wp_nav_menu()` do when developing WordPress themes.

WordPress will fallback menu to the lists of existing page if user don't assign. This can be disabled by passing the `fallback_cp` parameters to `wp_nav_menu()` like below:

```php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'fallback_cb'    => false, // Disables the fallback menu, which displays the pages added within your site.
    )
);
```

How can I disable such a fallback feature with Timber? I've read and search with keyword `fallback` in the [document](https://timber.github.io/docs/) of Timber. There's nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use conditions to achieve same functionality because of lacking support of `fallback` feature.

You can use the has_nav_menu() function to check if a menu is assigned to a specific theme location before rendering it in your template.

```
if( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    $context['menu'] = new Timber\Menu("primary");
}
```

Then in your Twig template, you can conditionally render the menu based on whether it exists in the context:

```
{% if menu %} 
   {% include "path/to/menu.twig" with {'menu': menu.get_items} %}
{% endif %}
```

This way, if no menu is assigned to the 'primary' theme location, no menu will be rendered, effectively disabling the fallback to a list of pages.